# Excellent web-editing software for Mac

Tags: macos

Can anyone suggest free web-editing software for a Mac? I'm running Snow Leopard. In particular, I want to be able to edit files on my site (I have FTP access). I don't want to have to download the file, edit it, and then re-upload it.

I currently use TextWrangler, but I don't like it too much. It's sometimes slow and buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what editor you use, it will be downloading, editing, and re-uploading the file.  You might want to look into better ways of managing your workflow, such as using rsync or svn repositories to keep your files in sync instead of having to think about uploading and downloading them.

Alternatively, if you have a way of accessing your file storage via WebDAV or sshfs, you can just mount the WebDAV share as a normal disk on OSX, and it will hide the upload/download details in the background and allow you to use whatever editor you like.

Answer (score 1):

Some people seem to love [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/). However it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) and [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/).  Transmit, as most FTP clients, allows remote editing (don't kid yourself, it's actually downloading, editing and uploading, but the program handles all that for you).  As mentioned above, [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) is also good one, as is [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Aptana http://aptana.com